# What are these bomb-shaped things attached to some propeller aircraft?

Tags: wing

[image: PA46]
I've seen them on a few prop machines and searched here and via Google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Oh it is indeed, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a weather radar pod.  On multi-engine aircraft, it is typical to install radar in the nose.  But that is not possible in a single engine propeller plane.  So, when radar is installed in one, it is most common to hang it under a wing as shown in the photo.  Here's a [link to such a pod](https://www.bennettavionics.com/4848x-2-v1-radar-pod-for-piper-malibu/)

Comment: Nice to know, thanks!